# How do I go from XIB to Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I've been trying a lot of things, to many to list. I'm using this code to go from a storyboard view controller to a XIB view controller:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        BLoginViewController *viewController=[[BLoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BLoginViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}

[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is, once the XIB view controller loads, I can't get back to the storyboard!

I've added a tool bar with a tool bar button on it named "Close". I connected the "Close" button with the XIB's viewcontroller.h file and I added `@synthesize closeButton;` to the XIB's viewcontroller.m file, then something like this in the XIB's viewcontroller.m file and linked it to the "Close" tool bar button:

`- (IBAction)closeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
}`

I don't know what code to put in the "Close" button to make it go back to the original starting storyboard view controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just simple dismissView controller if you present or popViewController if you navigate the XIB view controller from XIB viewcontroller close tap event

Comment: When I use dismissView controller, it hides the "BLoginViewController" for like a second, I see a different XIB view controller thats connected behind it and then the "BLoginViewController" pops right back up. It doesn't go back to the storyboard.

Comment: Can you post your navigation flow so I can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
```

or

use the following if your viewcontroller embedded into navigation controller

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: When I use dismissView controller, it hides the "BLoginViewController" for like a second, I see a different XIB view controller thats connected behind it and then the "BLoginViewController" pops right back up. It doesn't go back to the storyboard.

Comment: I tried using '[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];' but nothing happened.

Comment: your starting VC designed in storyboard is under navigation controller or not ??

Comment: it is not a navigation controller. the starting view controller is a view controller with a uitableview. it's sort of a settings menu.

Comment: I think while  logged in, the Loginviewcontroller also pulling up another view controller to show. You can recheck your presenting view controller for all scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `BAppTabBarController` from window Try this in `BAppTabBarController.m` file

```
@implementation BAppTabBarController

    - (IBAction)closeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];

    }

@end
```